# How can I install grub4dos to my USB stick?

Tags: bootloader

Though I searched for web I could not find a guide to install grub4dos into my USB stick in Ubuntu.

Is it possible in Ubuntu? If so, how can I install it into USB stick as a bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use grub2? 
It works on FAT32, NTFS or Linux formatted partitions.

Examples:
Label partition - if label is grub2 & mount:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/grub2 /dev/sdb
```

Newer versions automount with $USER name also, this one labeled MC4GB

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/fred/MC4GB /dev/sdb
```

And then you have to manually create your own grub.cfg file with the boot stanza for anything you want to boot. You can copy boot stanzas from your Ubuntu install, but may require some editing.

This will create a grub.cfg or you can just copy your own grub.cfg into /boot/grub. Again label in this example is MC4GB for may flash drive.

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /media/fred/MC4GB/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```